# Jquery DatePicker $.get request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to send some data to a script onSelect with DatePicker. Here is my code:

```
$( "#customdate" ).datepicker({
  nextText: "&#8594;",
  prevText: "&#8592;",
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
  maxDate: '-1d',
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var calendiv = $(this);
    var url = calendiv.data('href');
    var deets = calendiv.data();
    delete deets.href;
    deets.fromdate = dateText;
    $.get(url, deets, function(data) {
      alert("oh");
      if (data.success == 1) {
        var dataHTML = $.parseHTML(data.contents);
        $("#ideal tbody").html(dataHTML);
        $("#ideal").trigger('footable_initialize');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

However, when I click a date,I get the error below. Everything outside of the $.get works as expected, but nothing inside happens.

When I click it, I get the error:

> TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface HTMLElement.

Answer (score 0):

The first line after `onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {` should be `event.preventDefault`. Read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

If you but a `console.log($)` above `$.get(url, deets, function(data) {` you will see that it will be `undefined`. Read more about Javascript [contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

A working code should look like:

```
$( "#customdate" ).datepicker({
  nextText: "&#8594;",
  prevText: "&#8592;",
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
  maxDate: '-1d',
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var calendiv = $(this);
    var url = calendiv.data('href');
    var deets = calendiv.data();
    delete deets.href;
    deets.fromdate = dateText;
    $.get(url, deets, function(data) {
      alert("oh");
      if (data.success == 1) {
        var dataHTML = $.parseHTML(data.contents);
        $("#ideal tbody").html(dataHTML);
        $("#ideal").trigger('footable_initialize');
      }
    });
  }.bind(this)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I tried your solution but I'm getting "ReferenceError: event is not defined"